# Is the Platform on Stackexchange generic or be-spoke?

Tags: discussion, support, stackexchange

So I was googling something for some advice and came across a site that /has/ a simular styling to what I see on 'Stackexchange'. For example:

[image]

[This site here](http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/125704/how-to-restore-jailbroken-iphone-3gs-in-ios6)

I know it's a very small similarity, but on my quest around the world wide web, I have seen a lot more similarities.. So does Stackoverflow just use some kind of "forum" software package that is available to anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's built on OSQA, which is a well-known clone of Stack Exchange.

Stack Exchange is an original.

See also:

- [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/)
- [Are there better Stack Exchange alternatives/clones than OSQA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64661/are-there-better-stack-exchange-alternatives-clones-than-osqa)
- [Is Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow available for private or internal use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16054/is-the-stack-exchange-engine-available)

Comment: Thanks :) I visited the OSQA and found it useful